# Type of nil in Go

Tags: go, null

How can I handle `nil` return type in `switch-case` operators?

```
func someFunc() interface{}{
    if 5>2{
        return nil
    }else if something{
        return 42
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    switch someFunc().(type) {
    case int:
    case types.Nil:
        fmt.Println("5>2")
    }
}
```

This code prints nothing, but I expected "5>2". 
How should I do it properly?
https://play.golang.org/p/vAdiH925LDl

Comment: Why are you using the `types` package? Just check for `nil`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `nil`:

```
func main() {
    switch someFunc().(type) {
    case int:
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("5>2")
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XcJwM2wnGZG